# Navigation bar is translucent, but that is not what IB says

Tags: iphone

I think I must be going nuts here. I have a UINavigationController and in every view that I have pushed I have selected Black Navigation Bars in IB, but they all turn up as translucent ones.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Cmd+S to save it...?

Comment: Yes, this is throughout my application and there are currently three views in total that have a translucent navbar inspite of it being set to normal black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the [translucent](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) property on the UINavigationBar set properly?

Check your code to see if translucent is set somewhere or add this to your VC to print out the value:

```
NSLog(@"navBar.translucent = %d",
      (int)navController.navigationBar.translucent);
```

And check the Navigation Controller in IB, the Navigation Bar section should have a Style of Black Opaque (not Black Translucent), and an Alpha of 1.00.

[Nav Bar in IB http://morrisphotoart.com/tmp/Screen%20shot%202010-04-20%20at%2005.43.26.png](http://morrisphotoart.com/tmp/Screen%20shot%202010-04-20%20at%2005.43.26.png)

Comment: In IB I have selected Top Bar: Black Navigation Bar

Comment: No, not Top Bar under Simulated User Interface elements, you need to set the "Style" under "Navigation Bar" in "Navigation Bar Attributes".  Simulated User Interface elements are just place holders to help with your layout, they don't do anything.

Comment: OK that makes sense. This looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not re-declaring the color of the bar in code somewhere?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that I don't set it specifically to Translucent. I'm not sure however if this can be 'inherited' from somewhere else higher up in the hiearchy.